# Openssl Certificate Validation against multiple CA in a directory

Tags: validation, openssl, certificate, x509certificate, ca

```
  ret = X509_STORE_load_locations(store, NULL, “./”);
```

After compilation, I get the error

```
Verification return code: 0
Verification result text: unable to get local issuer certificate
Verification failed cert:
```

If my requirement is to validate a certificate against many CA certificates in a particular location, how should I implement it .
What should be the arguments for below function in that scenario? `ret = X509_STORE_load_locations(store, ca_bundlestr, NULL);`

Comment: Are the certificates in  the directory in hashed form ? Exact wording from the manual here..
X509_STORE_load_locations() loads trusted certificate(s) into an X509_STORE from a given file and/or directory path. It is permitted to specify just a file, just a directory, or both paths. The certificates in the directory must be in hashed form, as documented in X509_LOOKUP_hash_dir(3).

Comment: please can you share more code @
user3820915?